# Getting IP Address in C#

Tags: c#, ip, load-balancing

I currently have a RESTful C# web service that gets the client's IP address. This was working fine until load-balancing was implemented. So now the web service is sitting behind a load balancer.

Now, every time I try to get the user's IP address, I get the IP address of the load balancer instead. Here is what the code looks like...

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
            return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]);

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"))
            foreach (string ip in context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(','))
                if (CheckIP(ip.Trim()))
                    return new Model(ip.Trim());

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
            return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]);

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]))
            return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]);

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]);

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_FORWARDED") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
            return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]);

        return new Model(context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Despite this, I am still ultimately getting the wrong IP address. Any thoughts? Ideas? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you get a trace of the raw request coming in? If so, do any of the headers contain the original IP address? If not, you need to alter your load balancer to give you this data, or you're out of luck. If so, just request that header and get the data.

Comment: Try `X-Forwarded-For` for the HTTP header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well-behaved load balancer should place one *or more* IP addresses in the [**X_FORWARDED_FOR**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header.  Your code is checking **HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR** and two other variables that aren't quite right.

Not all load-balancers are well behaved, and some can be configured to include that header if it is not currently in there.

If there are multiple forwarding points, there will be multiple IP addresses in the header.  In that case, the first one listed is the client IP

> X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2

Comment: so I tried something like this...
string ip = context.Request.ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(',')[0];...but this doesn't seem to work. Is this a load balancer issue then?

Comment: If X_FORWARDED_FOR is not present in the HTTP headers, then the load balancer is not properly adding that header.  You should speak to the person administering the load balancer and explain that your code needs that header.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string sIpaddress = "";
        if (Request.Headers["True-Client-IP"] != null)
        {
            sIpaddress = Request.Headers["True-Client-IP"]; //if the user is behind a proxy server
        }
        if (sIpaddress == "")
        {
            if (Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"] != null)
                sIpaddress = Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"];
        }
        if (sIpaddress == "")
        {
            if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
                sIpaddress = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
        }
        if (sIpaddress == "")
        {
            if (Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] != null)
                sIpaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

Comment: Hi.

Please have a look at the response you give. There are several formatting errors.
Also, please ["read this article"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before posting a answer.